# NPCs won't talk in Goodneighbor (minor spoilers)

Tags: fallout-4

When I first visited Goodneighbor on my first playthrough, there was a showdown between two guys (Finn was one of them i think). After it was over I was greeted by Hancock and he gave my both a quest and some pointers.

Now on my second playthrough Finn, Hancock and Fahrenheit are just standing around by KL-E-0's shop and I'm unable to talk to either. Finn is "busy" and the other two just spurt random dialogue. No dialogue wheel appears.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: +1 to what @DangerZone said - I've seen a video where the player kills Finn and the game continues as if Hancock kills him as per the scripted sequence.

Comment: @LoboDemon, do you think I should just post it as an answer?

Comment: @DangerZone - Yeah, go for it. I believe that this would work as a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way to typically end this dialogue is to kill Finn yourself (I believe Hancock even has separate dialogue if you do).

Since Hancock's sequence isn't being triggered for whatever reason, it is likely that doing so will sort of kick start/trigger him into becoming active rather than busy.

As LoboDemon mentioned in their comment on the question itself, it has been confirmed that this has at least worked in *some* capacity.

Comment: Here's a link to a gif of this working that I was referring to:  https://giant.gfycat.com/OddballZealousGreyhounddog.gif